# Firefox 57 / block Javascript per site

Tags: firefox, javascript, blocking, firefox-57

As you all might know, Mozilla is migrating its addon system to WebExtension and so many addons break from version 57+, see more here:

https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2016/11/23/add-ons-in-2017/

In the past I used "Yes Script" and "No Script" to allow Javascript everywhere and block it on specific sites only. However they are not supported in FF 57 (I'm on beta now) and the developer of "Yes Script" does not plan to upgrade it in the future. But I'd like to block JS on specific sites. Any idea how I might achieve that?

Could I do that modifying prefs.js or user.js? I would prefer to do this without any extension if possible. Thanks.

Comment: Someone suggested uMatrix

Comment: You may use WaterFox with legacy support.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved it by developing an extension myself: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/yesscript2/

Comment: I've reached version 4.0 where Sync works fine and I've changed functionality: There are 3 states from now on instead of the original 2 ones: 1) no blocking (grey icon), 2) half blocking (internal script are enabled while externals are blocked, blue icon), 3) full blocking (internal and external scripts are blocked too, red icon)

Comment: The hero we don't deserve!

Comment: Is there a reason this cannot work on older versions of FireFox?  I have an older computer, and was hoping to be able to use an add-on this simple on it...

Answer (score 4):

[uBlock Origin](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/) in "advanced mode" can block scripts with so-called dynamic filtering rules. It also distinguishes scripts between inline, 1st party and 3rd party. You can set up a default policy of blocking for all sites and selectively override it for specific sites.

Update:
[uMatrix](https://github.com/gorhill/uMatrix) is even better and allows more fine-grained control

Comment: Actually I solved it by developing an extension myself. Consider the question solved. Thanks. See it here: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/yesscript2/

Comment: to "solve" the question you need to accept your own answer

Answer (score 2):

It isn't possible to disable JavaScript per domain without an add-on.

[NoScript](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/noscript/) version 10 has been released, it supports Firefox 57.

Or you may want to try [uMatrix](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/umatrix/) as a replacement, it's even more powerful in that it allows you to block not only scripts but also cookies, ajax, media, etc. And everything per third-party domain.

It is also [still possible](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Add-ons/Firefox57) to reenable support for legacy add-ons. But you'll have to use [Developer Edition](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/) or [Nightly](https://nightly.mozilla.org/) for it to work. Once you are there, set `extensions.legacy.enabled` to `true` in `about:config`. It's also [going to be available](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1414450) in the Beta and Release unbranded builds, but not yet.

Comment: My understanding is that the `extensions.legacy.enabled` hack was included for testing purposes in pre-release versions only.  The code to support the legacy extensions is missing in the actual V57 release.  Bummer!

Comment: @fixer1234, thanks for the info, updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I installed the "Disable JavaScript" extension and so far it works fine:
https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/addon/disable-javascript/